# How can I open a local html file in shiny for python?

Tags: python, html, py-shiny

link to local html files is not opening in shiny for python.
Adding the file to the www folder does not seem to solve the problem.
Any hint will be very helpful.

I have added a link for my local html file as show in the code below. However opening the link leads to a no found message as shown in the attached image. I have tried placing the file in the www folder but made no difference.

```
def server(input, output, session):  
 @output
 @render.ui
 def link():
  return ui.a("Click here", href = "help.html" , target = "_blank")
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hBhM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recently managed to get this working by reading in the html before specifying the app ui using the below code:

```
with open("file_name_here.html", 'r') as file: 
    html_as_string = file.read()
```

And then in the ui specify it like this:

```
ui.HTML(html_as_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method, which leverages [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/), the ASGI framework Shiny for Python is based on. You can find more info here, in the [Static file section](https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/).

I included a working UI, similar to what I used

```
app_ui = x.ui.page_fillable(
ui.navset_tab_card(
    ui.nav(
        'Some basic Nav',
        ui.navset_pill(
            ui.nav_menu(
                x.ui.tooltip("Your Menu with Links", "These links will open in a new tab", id="link_info"),
                ui.nav_control(ui.a("Your new tab", href="/page", target="_blank")))
        )),
))
```

Then I used the example from Shiny for [routing](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/workflow-server.html)

```
your_app = App(app_ui, server)

app_routes = [
    Mount('/page', app=StaticFiles(directory='./your_path', html=True)),
    Mount('/some_url', app=your_app)
]

app = Starlette(routes=app_routes)
```

According to the Starlette documentation if you add the `html=True` argument and your directory contains an `index.html` file in it, that HTML file will be loaded on that path.

With this method, you need to create a path to your main app, too. But I did not find that to be an issue.